Making a regression table to compare multiple models side by side in R but "length of NULL cannot be changed" error
I'm running a linear regression model and then a standard error mean model + trying to view their results together in a table
lm1 <- lm(foodsec_pct_male ~ 
            log(agri_employment_share) + 
            log(gdp_pc) + 
            log(agri_developmentflows_share) + # proportion of development flows to agriculture (of total dev. flows)
            log(dailycarbsup_pc), # daily carbohydrate supply (in grams per person)
          data=foodsec_sp_clean2)

sem1 <- errorsarlm(foodsec_pct_male ~ 
                     log(agri_employment_share) + 
                     log(gdp_pc) + 
                     log(agri_developmentflows_share) + 
                     log(dailycarbsup_pc), 
                   data = foodsec_sp_clean2,
                   listw = wq2,
                   zero.policy = TRUE) # consider areas with no neighbours in our analysis

summary(sem1)

stargazer(lm1, sem1, 
          type = "html", 
          out = "practical7_tab1.html",
          title = "Regression Results",
          column.labels = c("OLS", "SEM"),
          covariate.labels = c("Log of Agricultural employment (%)", 
                               "Log of GDP p.c.", 
                               "Log of Agricultural development flows (%)", 
                               "Log of daily carb supply p.c. (grams)"),
          dep.var.caption = "Dependent variable:",
          dep.var.labels = "Food insecurity (% Male)",
          omit.stat = c("ll",  "ser", "f", "wald", "lr")) # Omit specified statistics from comparative reg table

Running the models is fine but when I run stargazer() I get this error:
Warning: length of NULL cannot be changedWarning: length of NULL cannot be changedWarning: length of NULL cannot be changedWarning: length of NULL cannot be changedWarning: length of NULL cannot be changed
<table style="text-align:center"><caption><strong>Regression Results</strong></caption>
<tr><td colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td colspan="2">Dependent variable:</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td colspan="2" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td colspan="2">Food insecurity (% Male)</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td><em>OLS</em></td><td><em>spatial</em></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td><em></em></td><td><em>error</em></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>OLS</td><td>SEM</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>(1)</td><td>(2)</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">Log of Agricultural employment (%)</td><td>-2.156</td><td>-2.730</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>(3.318)</td><td>(2.993)</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Log of GDP p.c.</td><td>-16.267<sup>***</sup></td><td>-13.195<sup>***</sup></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>(2.611)</td><td>(2.429)</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Log of Agricultural development flows (%)</td><td>2.044</td><td>1.831</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>(1.684)</td><td>(1.485)</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Log of daily carb supply p.c. (grams)</td><td>-39.697<sup>***</sup></td><td>-32.851<sup>***</sup></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>(12.375)</td><td>(11.697)</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Constant</td><td>412.963<sup>***</sup></td><td>347.433<sup>***</sup></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>(76.947)</td><td>(73.213)</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">Observations</td><td>88</td><td>88</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">R<sup>2</sup></td><td>0.528</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Adjusted R<sup>2</sup></td><td>0.505</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">sigma<sup>2</sup></td><td></td><td>211.802</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Akaike Inf. Crit.</td><td></td><td>739.810</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left"><em>Note:</em></td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:right"><sup>*</sup>p<0.1; <sup>**</sup>p<0.05; <sup>***</sup>p<0.01</td></tr>
</table>

This is what chatGPT suggested:
stargazer(lm1, sem1, type="text")

ChatGPT's suggestion's output:
Warning: length of NULL cannot be changedWarning: length of NULL cannot be changedWarning: length of NULL cannot be changedWarning: length of NULL cannot be changedWarning: length of NULL cannot be changed
==========================================================================
                                            Dependent variable:           
                                 -----------------------------------------
                                             foodsec_pct_male             
                                          OLS                spatial      
                                                              error       
                                          (1)                  (2)        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
log(agri_employment_share)               -2.156               -2.730      
                                        (3.318)              (2.993)      
                                                                          
log(gdp_pc)                            -16.267***           -13.195***    
                                        (2.611)              (2.429)      
                                                                          
log(agri_developmentflows_share)         2.044                1.831       
                                        (1.684)              (1.485)      
                                                                          
log(dailycarbsup_pc)                   -39.697***           -32.851***    
                                        (12.375)             (11.697)     
                                                                          
Constant                               412.963***           347.433***    
                                        (76.947)             (73.213)     
                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                               88                   88        
R2                                       0.528                            
Adjusted R2                              0.505                            
Log Likelihood                                               -362.905     
sigma2                                                       211.802      
Akaike Inf. Crit.                                            739.810      
Residual Std. Error                 16.218 (df = 83)                      
F Statistic                      23.210*** (df = 4; 83)                   
Wald Test                                               17.989*** (df = 1)
LR Test                                                 9.130*** (df = 1) 
==========================================================================
Note:                                          *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01

this is better but I want this to be an actual table + follow the rules I set out in my original code
